# What's the African Union's Plan on accomplishing the Agenda 2063 for transforming Africa?

Tags: sustainable-development, african-union, agenda-2063

I am aware that the African Union (AU) has plans on sustainable development and I am curious about how the AU plans to fulfill this mind-blowing idea and would help be needed from outside the African borders to accomplish the African Dream? And if the African Union didn't make some indications on the matter, what could the African Union do to accomplish the initiative?

> **[Agenda 2063: The Africa We Want.](https://au.int/en/agenda2063/overview)**
>
> AGENDA 2063 is Africa’s blueprint and master plan for transforming Africa into the global powerhouse of the future. It is the continent’s strategic framework that aims to deliver on its goal for inclusive and sustainable development and is a concrete manifestation of the pan-African drive for unity, self-determination, freedom, progress, and collective prosperity pursued under Pan-Africanism and African Renaissance The genesis of Agenda 2063 was the realization by African leaders that there was a need to refocus and reprioritize Africa’s agenda from the struggle against apartheid and the attainment of political independence for the continent which had been the focus of The Organisation of African Unity (OAU), the precursor of the African Union; and instead to prioritize inclusive social and economic development, continental and regional integration, democratic governance and peace and security amongst other issues aimed at repositioning Africa to becoming a dominant player in the global arena.

Answer (score 3):

The African Union is an intergovernmental organisation.  Its remit is to allow for the various states in Africa to cooperate to achieve their goals. It facilitates discussion rather than executing actions.

The AU has several "[flagship projects](https://au.int/en/agenda2063/flagship-projects)" that the various states want to achieve in order to reach the aspiration of "making Africa a global powerhouse":

- An integrated high-speed train network
- A cooperative commodities strategy
- A continental free trade area
- The free movement of people across Africa
- An end to civil and international war
- A single African air transport market
- An African Economic Forum
- The establishment of African economic institutions (An African investment bank, stock exchange, monetary fund, and central bank)
- A secure, independent and fast electronic network and
- A university structure that takes advantage of this network.

Some of these only require political will: The end of fighting on the continent "only" requires all belligerents to choose a peaceful way to settle their disputes. The AU can provide a forum for negotiated peace talks.

Similarly a free trade area requires only the political will to achieve, and the belief that free trade is in the long term interest of each country, even when there is a short term risk.  Likewise the free movement and commodities strategy.  There are short and long term risks in an individual state taking the steps needed to achieve a commodities strategy.

The electronic network would, most likely, need to licence technology from Asia, Europe or America; as would the high-speed train network.  There is also investment needed to build these networks.  Again the source of the investment may include outside investors.

So at the end of the day, the AU can't itself achieve much of this.  However if you view the AU as the sum of its members, the states of Africa could. Much of the purpose of the AU is to allow member states to develop the political will and intergovernmental trust needed to enable these projects to go ahead.